# While setting kubernetes cluster, kubeadm initialization command is giving error

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-vm-templates

I am trying to set up Kubernetes cluster on Azure ubuntu-16.04 LTS VM. I installed docker 17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial version on VM and followed all steps mentioned on kubernetes official website but while running kubeadm command on my master node I am getting error.

My init command:

```
 kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=<ip>
```

Error Message:

```
[init] using Kubernetes version: v1.11.3
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: the kubelet version is higher than the control 
plane version. This is not a supported version skew and may lead to a 
malfunctional cluster. Kubelet version: "1.12.0-rc.1" Control plane version: 
"1.11.3"
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal 
with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a newer version of the `kubelet` - `v1.12.0-rc.1` than that of `kubeadm` - `v1.11.3`.  You can try:

1. Downgrading the kubelet to match your kubeadm version

   On Ubuntu run: `apt-get -y install kubelet=1.11.3-00`
2. The other way around, upgrade kubeadm to match that of the kubelet

   On Ubuntu run: `apt-get -y install kubeadm=1.12.0-rc.1-00`
3. `--ignore-preflight-errors` like it says, but watch if you see any other errors that may make your installation not work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any command or reference document to follow mentioned steps. I am new to kubernetes and not having much idea n this. So if you can refer something that would be of great help.

Comment: no luck.. :( . I figured out one thing that I dont have any admin.conf  file in /etc/kubernetes/ directory. Not sure if this can be the reason

Comment: Before trying anything again on any of your nodes. Try running `kubeadm reset`. That will delete everything and make you start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have posted is definitely related to what @Rico described, there was a version update lately, and many people had this issue (including me). You can see the releases [here.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/)
Seems like some time after the release of the new version, the `apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl` would download or match the incorrect version of components.

When I had this issue, downloading the Kubernetes version manually (
`kubeadm config images pull --kubernetes-version v1.11.3`) and then running `kubeadm init` with a flag marking which version I want to run worked for me. Another option is to upgrade kubeadm (`apt-get upgrade kubeadm`).

However, as I tested this on clean install just a few minutes ago, everything works fine out of the box.

You can remove the kubelet, kubeadm, and kubectl and install them again with the recommended commands from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl) or try `kubeadm reset` and then match the versions or update components as proposed by Rico. Do not forget to run:

`mkdir -p $HOME/.kube

sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`

after cluster initialization.